# How to break a cycle with a String?

Tags: java, arrays, string

I want to give user a possibility to stop inputing new lines in my String array by entering the word "end". I checked out - it really inputs 'end' before the if statement, but for some reason this doesn't break the while cycle:

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);           
String[] str = new String[50];                    
int j=0;
int f = 0;                           
System.out.println("Input 'end' to see your previous input!");
while(f != -1)
{
```

the input goes well, but the if statement doesn't work completely

```
 String choice = scan.nextLine();   
             if(choice == "end")               
             {
                 f = -1;              
             }
             else
             {
                 str[j] = choice;
                 j++;
             }
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

`choice.equals("end")` instead of `==`

See [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html)

Also see [equalsIgnoreCase()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) method for string comparision